# SSDT Generate Script Permission

Tags: sql-server-data-tools

I would like to allow a user to generate SSDT database script but restrict to deploy it.

What permission is required on the database for this?

https://the.agilesql.club/2015/04/what-permissions-do-i-need-to-generate-a-deploy-script-with-ssdt/ suggest that it needs permission on dbo.__Refactorlog table but I can't find this table.

Comment: reader, show definition. The same is written in your given URL

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where can I find dbo.__Refactorlog? It looks like this table is no longer generated.

Comment: It should be created if you do any refactoring